# How to add a point or marker for the last date in a time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

In the code below, I'm trying to convert the last data point for each variable into a point or a different marker. What modification should I do to to achive this?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(economics_long, aes(date, value))+ geom_line() + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a `geom_point` layer where you use a dataset filtered for the last date, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(economics_long, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = group_by(economics_long, variable) %>% filter(date == last(date))) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)
```

[image]